# How to repeat values X times based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba, copying

Each row of item number, pack, and size is to be repeated multiple times in a separate sheet based on the number in the column "number of labels".

Note: The number in the number of labels is for test purposes and does not need to increment.

Sheet 1 would be as follows

```
Item #  Pack    Size    Number of Labels
12545   20      1.8oz   1
56010   6       4PK     2
70091   6       7oz     3
61816   24      1.6oz   4
```

I would like sheet 2 to output the following:

```
Item #  Pack    Size
12545   20      1.8oz
56010   6        4PK
56010   6        4PK
70091   6        7oz
70091   6        7oz
70091   6        7oz
61816   24       1.6oz
61816   24       1.6oz
61816   24       1.6oz
61816   24       1.6oz
```

I found the following code from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1897-excel-repeat-cell-value-x-times.html#a2 to output multiple columns. I want the cell input ranges to be fixed and to not use the dialog boxes.

```vb
Sub CopyData()
'Update 20140724
Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")
For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
    xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
    xNum = Rng.Range("B1").Value
    OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Context: I have to create many labels for new products. I manually type each label in Word. I found that I could use Word's Mail merge operation to import Excel data. I have those parts working but now I need to get the exact number of labels for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub hereyago()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim wsO As Worksheet
    Dim this As Integer

    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 4)) Then
            this = arr(i, 4)
            For h = 1 To this
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = arr(i, 1)
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = arr(i, 2)
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = arr(i, 3)
                wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = arr(i, 4)
            Next h
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```