# How to repeat values X times based on a cell value, including a repeated pattern

Tags: excel, vba

Data input in columns A - E. Desired outcome in columns G - K.
[image: input and desired outcome]

Code I tired to edit:

- 'https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4054-excel-duplicate-rows-based-on-cell-value.html#a1
- [How to repeat values X times based on a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207227/excel-how-to-repeat-multiple-values-based-on-a-cell-value-x-times)

The steps:

1. Each "Folder" value needs to be repeated down by the number ((Quantity *5)+1) - Desired outcome shown in Column H. There are 11 No. "A" followed by 16 No. "B".
2. The "Sub-folder" value is repeated down, offset (1,0), repeated down by 5, then the next sequential number starts being repeated down again by 5 and so on... carries on 1, 2, 3 etc. Desired outcome in Column I.
3. The "Document Type" value is repeated down, offset (2,0), repeated down by 4, then 1No. blank cell and repeat down by 4 again. Desired outcome in Column J.
4. The "Document Number" will always be 1, 2, or 3. the subsequent numbering should start offset (3,0), then 2No. blank cells, then sequential numbering again 1 - 3.

I am trying to create a document control system where the document names are identified before the project starts. The "Unique Document Number" includes a formula to give the unique number. The reason for the gaps is I can conditional format the cells into colours to identify headings and sub-headings.

There could be 12 No. folders A - L and within them 6 sub-folders 001 - 006, making the list very long. Having recognised the pattern I feel this could be automated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an effort to solve this without VBA
You need a couple of helper columns:

```
P repetitions
P2 = E2
P3 = =IF(P2>1,P2-1,INDIRECT("E" & Q3))

Q row
Q2 = 2
Q3 = =IF(P2>1,Q2,Q2+1)

R First Sub Number Helper
R3 = 1
R4 = =IF(MOD(P4,5)>0,R3,R3+1)
```

Then to your table:

```
G1 = =H2&IF(I2<>"","-"&I2,"")&IF(J2<>"","-"&J2,"")&IF(K2<>"","-"&K2,"")
H1 = A2
H2 = =IF(P2>1,H1,INDIRECT("A" & Q3))
I3 = R3
I4 = =IF(P4>P3,"",R4)
J2 = =IF(OR(I2="",MOD(P2,5)=0),"",XLOOKUP(H2,A:A,C:C))
K1 = =IFS(OR(J2="",MOD(P2,5)>3),"",MOD(P2,5)=3,1,MOD(P2,5)=2,2,MOD(P2,5)=1,3)
```

Drag down all columns as appropriate.
[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! I have tweaked the code to suit but thanks for general idea of how to get it to work. One comment, I presume in your code above "H2" you have referenced "H2" in the formula, it works when this is "H1", I presume this is correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the correction I have updated the answer accordingly.